# Type-inference in Dart ... is there a bug?

Tags: dart, type-inference

The following program worked fine some time ago. Now typeinference seems to have a bug. Before reporting a bug I want to make sure that the problem with type-inference is not my fault.

The program is a transscript of the standard trampolining library (TailCalls.scala) of Scala version 13.0. Hence, I assume the correctness of the dart program.

```
abstract class TailRec<A> {
  A value;

  A result() {
    TailRec<A> tr = this;
    while (!(tr is _Done<A>)) {
      if (tr is _Bounce<A>) {
        tr = (tr as _Bounce<A>).continuation();
      } else if (tr is Cont) {
        var a = (tr as Cont).a;
        var f = (tr as Cont).f;
        if (a is _Done) {
          tr = f(a.value);
        } else if (a is _Bounce) {
          tr = a.continuation().flatMap<A>(f);
        } else if (a is Cont) {
          var b = a.a;
          var g = a.f;
          tr = b.flatMap<A>((x) => g(x).flatMap<A>(f));
        } else {
          throw new Exception("#1");
        }
      } else {
        throw new Exception("#2");
      }
    }
    return tr.value;
  }

  A compute() {
    TailRec<A> res = this;

    while (!res._isDone) {
      final _Bounce<A> bounce = res;
      res = bounce.continuation();
    }
    _Done<A> done = res;
    return done.value;
  }

  bool get _isDone;



  TailRec<B> map<B>(B Function(A) f) {
    return flatMap((a) => new _Bounce(() => new _Done<B>(f(a))));
  }

  TailRec<B> flatMap<B>(TailRec<B> Function(A) f) {
    if (this is _Done) {
      return new _Bounce(() => f(this.value));
    } else if (this is _Bounce) {
      return new Cont(this, f);
    } else if (this is Cont) {
      Cont<A, B> c = (this as Cont<A, B>);
      return new Cont<A, B>(c.a, (A x) => c.f(x).flatMap(f));  
      /*
      in the application of flatMap the falsely required type is:
        TailRec<B> TailRec.flatMap<B>(TailRec<B> Function(B) f)
      this is at odds with the definition of flatMap
      the correct type given is:
        TailRec<B> Function(A) f
      */
    } else {
      throw new Exception("#3");
    }
  }
}

class Cont<A, B> extends TailRec<B> {
  Cont(this.a, this.f);
  TailRec<A> a;
   TailRec<B> Function(A x) f;
  @override
  bool get _isDone => false;
}

class _Done<A> extends TailRec<A> {
  _Done(this.value);
  @override
  final A value;
  @override
  final bool _isDone = true;
}


class _Bounce<A> extends TailRec<A> {
  _Bounce(TailRec<A> Function()f) {
    this.continuation = f;
  }
  TailRec<A> Function()continuation; 
  @override
  final bool _isDone = false;
}

TailRec<A> done<A>(A x) => new _Done<A>(x);

TailRec<A> tailcall<A>(TailRec<A> continuation()) => new _Bounce(continuation);
```

In the application of flatMap the falsely required type is:

```
flatMap<B>(TailRec<B> Function(B) f)
```

The definition of flatMap shows the correctly required type:

```
flatMap<B>(TailRec<B> Function(A) f) {
```

So, exactly this should determine the required type.

Type-inference falsely concludes a 'B' instead of an 'A'.

The  correctly given type is:

```
TailRec<B> Function(A) f
```

I am using dart version 2.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot consider a Dart expression of the form

```dart
if (tr is _Bounce) {
  ...
} else if (tr is Cont) {
  ...
} ...
```

as comparable to the corresponding match expression in the Scala standard libraries: The former will promote `tr` to `_Bounce<dynamic>` in the first block, `Cont<dynamic, dynamic>` in the second block, etc.

In contrast, the Scala match is subject to static analysis which will perform type inference on the pattern matching terms, and they will allow you to denote the type arguments even when they are unknown.

(E.g., `case c: Cont[a1, b1] => Cont(c.a, (x: a1) => c.f(x) flatMap f)` from [here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/43e040ff7e4ba92ccf223e77540580b32c1473c0/src/library/scala/util/control/TailCalls.scala#L62) uses the type `a1`, which is the unknown type that Slava called `?` [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/38232#issuecomment-528823184))

However, it is possible to express the Scala library (taken from [here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.0/src/library/scala/util/control/TailCalls.scala)) in a way that makes the types available to the static analysis.

Note that the version of the Scala library that I found uses `Either`, so I added a couple of skeleton declarations to make the resulting code self-contained.

Here's the code:

```
// ------------------------------ Skeleton emulation of Scala standard stuff.

class Either<A, B> {}

class Left<A, B> implements Either<A, B> {
  Left(this.value);
  A value;
}

class Right<A, B> implements Either<A, B> {
  Right(this.value);
  B value;
}

abstract class Option<A> {
  A get value;
  const Option();
  B Function(B Function(A)) fold<B>(B ifEmpty()) =>
      (B f(A a)) => isEmpty ? ifEmpty() : f(value);
  bool get isEmpty;
}

class Some<A> extends Option<A> {
  final A value;
  Some(this.value);
  get isEmpty => false;
}

class _None extends Option<Null /*soon: Never*/ > {
  get value => throw "Attempt to do None.value";
  const _None();
  get isEmpty => true;
}

const None = _None();

// ------------------------------ TailCall.

typedef LazyTailRec<X> = TailRec<X> Function();

abstract class TailRec<A> {
  TailRec<B> map<B>(B Function(A) f) =>
      flatMap((a) => _Call(() => _Done(f(a))));
  TailRec<B> flatMap<B>(TailRec<B> Function(A) f);
  A get result;
  Either<LazyTailRec<A>, A> get _resume;
  B _result1<B>(_Cont<A, B> c);
  Either<LazyTailRec<B>, B> _resume1<B>(_Cont<A, B> c);

  static C _result0<D, C>(TailRec<D> b, _Cont<D, C> c) => b._result1(c);
  static Either<LazyTailRec<C>, C> _resume0<D, C>(
          TailRec<D> b, _Cont<D, C> c) =>
      b._resume1(c);
}

class _Call<A> extends TailRec<A> {
  final LazyTailRec<A> rest;
  _Call(this.rest);
  flatMap<B>(f) => _Cont(this, f);
  get result => rest().result;
  get _resume => Left(rest);
  _result1<B>(c) => rest().flatMap(c.f).result;
  _resume1<B>(c) => Left(() => rest().flatMap(c.f));
}

class _Cont<B, A> extends TailRec<A> {
  TailRec<B> b;
  TailRec<A> Function(B) f;
  _Cont(this.b, this.f);
  flatMap<C>(g) => _Cont(b, (B x) => f(x).flatMap(g));
  get result => TailRec._result0<B, A>(b, this);
  get _resume => TailRec._resume0<B, A>(b, this);
  _result1<C>(c) => b.flatMap((B x) => f(x).flatMap(c.f)).result;
  _resume1<C>(c) => b.flatMap((B x) => f(x).flatMap(c.f))._resume;
}

class _Done<A> extends TailRec<A> {
  final A value;
  _Done(this.value);
  flatMap<B>(f) => _Call(() => f(value));
  get result => value;
  get _resume => Right(value);
  _result1<B>(c) => c.f(value).result;
  _resume1<B>(c) => c.f(value)._resume;
}

TailRec<A> tailcall<A>(TailRec<A> rest) => _Call(() => rest);
TailRec<A> done<A>(A result) => _Done(result);
```

We're considering an extension of Dart with explicit and strictly statically checked variance (cf. [this issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/524)), and you could add a few `out` and `inout` modifiers on type parameters to get fully strict checks, but I believe that the above form is the most strictly checked form that you can have in Dart today.

Here's an example:

```
// -------------------------------------------------- Test.

TailRec<int> test(int a) => a > 10
    ? tailcall(Some(true).fold(() => test(a - 1))((_) => test(a - 2)))
    : done(-1);

main() => print(test(11).result); // -1.
```

PS: I didn't worry about the original point of having this, i.e., the property that certain calls are in a tail position that the Scala compiler can recognize and generate jumps rather than calls for; the Dart compiler won't do that anyway, and I was more interested in the ability to express the typing situations than controlling the stack height.